# Lean FT: track *.tsrx.cs files with version control like git?

Tags: git, version-control, leanft

I am new to Lean FT and was wondering about a decent `.gitignore` template. Lean FT generates `*.tsrx` files for app models and corresponding `*.tsrx.cs` files containing header information that explains these files are automatically generated. I assume that it is a good idea to add the `*.tsrx.cs` files to `.gitignore` and simply not track them, but I would like to get a second opinion. The `*.tsrx` are quite important and should be tracked in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you use the project.

If whoever checks out the project generates the `tsrx.cs` files themselves, you are good to go (can ignore them).

In C# they are generated in two ways, as stated [here](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.50-14.52/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/update-appModel.htm#mt-item-0):

1. The LeanFT IDE plugin automatically generates the code file when the LeanFT project is opened in the IDE.
   In your case, opening the project in VS will generate those files
2. Using a command line tool. This method is recommended when you want to generate the code file or multiple code files without opening your LeanFT projects. For details, see [AppModel code generation tool.](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.50-14.52/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/update-appModel.htm#AppModel)

Comment: I cannot really imagine a use case where you want to checkout the source code and not generate the files. Additionally, I noticed them because VS replaced all generated files by newer versions, because the first author used an older Lean FT version than me. So even if there are checked out, VS will overwrite them (if needed). Thanks a lot!